# Abstract class with little used abstract method - should I make concrete?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class called GUIElement described by this code:

```
public abstract class GUIElement {
    public abstract void onScroll();
    //Other methods such as getX(), getY(), onClick() etc.
}
```

All GUI elements that extend this are obviously forced to write concrete code for onScroll provided they are a concrete class, but very few actually use this onScroll method as it is only handy in something like a long GUIText block.

My question is then, what is the best practice in this situation? Continue to force all child classes to write code even when mostly it will be empty, or make it concrete like so:

```
public abstract class GUIElement {
    public void onScroll() {}
    //Other methods such as getX(), getY(), onClick() etc.
}
```

and have the few classes that use it just override it.
Or maybe there are other, better alternatives?

Comment: You could also create an interface implementing it as default method. As opposed to having the onScroll() method implemented as an empty method in the ABC, you can even test is that specific Class/Object is scrollable. Or: you could implement the method in the ABC, and give it a boolean return value to see if it supports scrolling at all, with the ABC returning false as a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only a few classes need to implement the method, then the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is a good choice. Which is, what your second approach basically is. Have an empty implementation in the parent class and only those child classes that need this functionality can override it, but they're not forced to do so.

Take a look at the [MouseAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.java) in the AWT package for instance. It implements the `MouseListener` interface, but leaves all methods empty. Child classes then can choose whether to override those methods or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I have a class called GUIElement described by this code:
>
> ```
> public abstract class GUIElement {
>     public abstract void onScroll();
>     //Other methods such as getX(), getY(), onClick() etc.
> }
> ```
>
> All GUI elements that extend this are obviously forced to write concrete code for onScroll provided they are a concrete class, but very few actually use this onScroll method as it is only handy in something like a long GUIText block.

In an abstract class methods should be abstract because concrete methods in this abstract class use them, e.g.:

```
public abstract class GUIElement {
    public void onScroll(){
      // do stuff
      SomeObject retunValue = calculateInSomeChiledClass();
      // do other stuff
    } 

    potected abstract SomeObject calculateInSomeChiledClass();
}
```

An abstract class should not have abstract methods for any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty concrete method is a way but it has a consequence as it doesn't force new declared class to override it.
If this consequence is not a drawback for you, using this way is fine.

Otherwise, if you want to be sure that subclasses specify explicitly how to implement the operation, you should keep the method as abstract and implement them when it is required and throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` or an empty implementation in the subclasses where the operation is not supported.

Both solutions are acceptable.
Follow the one or the second depends on the point that you want to stress on for your subclasses : simple API or explicit behavior to define.